# How to use/ deploy Qt Sensors Qml app to my device

Tags: qt, compilation, qml

I'm having real trouble getting QSensors class for qml to work and I really can't find any useful tutorials or faq's on how to do this. I have used the example apps they have already in qt quick and I have tried to do my own app with all the resources I can find online about this subject with no avail.

Can anyone help me with the steps I need to be able to use QSensors in my qml application. Or point me in the right direction to a good step by step guide to a successful compile to android.I'm compiling for android on windows 8 incase that is of any importance.

Thanks for the help in advanced

In response to the comments below:

if i include the

```
QT += sensors
// and in my qml file
import QtSensors 5.0
```

then I can compile to my android but I receive this error when I click on the screen

```
D/GraphicBuffer(26197): create handle(0x761ce210) (w:720, h:1230, f:1)
D/GraphicBuffer(26197): create handle(0x761d0058) (w:720, h:1230, f:1)
D/VelocityTracker(26197): Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (No such file or directory)
D/VelocityTracker(26197): tpd read x fail: Bad file number
D/VelocityTracker(26197): tpd read y fail: Bad file number
D/dalvikvm(26197): threadid=11: bye!
D/dalvikvm(26197): threadid=11: interp stack at 0x74b26000
D/dalvikvm(26197): threadid=11: bye!
```

this is my header file

```
# Add more folders to ship with the application, here
folder_01.source = qml/SensorTester
folder_01.target = qml
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS = folder_01

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# The .cpp file which was generated for your project. Feel free to hack it.
SOURCES += main.cpp
QT += quick
QT=core gui
QT += sensors
CONFIG += plugin
CONFIG += ordered

INCLUDEPATH += C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\Src\qtsensors\src\imports\sensors

# Installation path
# target.path =

# Please do not modify the following two lines. Required for deployment.
include(qtquick2applicationviewer/qtquick2applicationviewer.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()
```

and my qml file

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtSensors 5.0

Rectangle {
    id: gesturerect
    border.width: 1
    anchors.margins: 5

    property string selectedGesture: ""

    SensorGesture {
        id: gesture
    }

    Text {
        id: labelGesture
        anchors.top: gesturerect.top
        anchors.left: gesturerect.left
        anchors.right: gesturerect.right
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        font.pixelSize: 30
        font.bold: true
        text: "Gestures"
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: gestureListRect
        border.width: 1
        anchors.top: labelGesture.bottom
        anchors.left: gesturerect.left
        anchors.right: gesturerect.right
        anchors.bottom: gesturerect.bottom
        anchors.margins: 5

//! [4]
        ListView {
            id: gestureList
//! [4]
            anchors.fill: gestureListRect
            anchors.margins: 5
//! [5]
            model: gesture.availableGestures
//! [5]
            focus: true
            currentIndex: -1
            delegate: gestureListDelegate
            clip: true
//! [6]
        }
//! [6]

        Component {
            id: gestureListDelegate

            Rectangle {
                width: gestureList.width
                height: itemText.height
                color: (index === gestureList.currentIndex ? "#999933" : "#FFFFFF")

                Text {
                    id: itemText
                    text: model.modelData
                }
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        gestureList.currentIndex = index
                        selectedGesture = model.modelData
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATED

Thanks to everyones help I've got it working but still with some complications.
I took another example from `http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtsensors-shakeit-example.html`

on my vivo y20t:

```
onDetected:{
            console.debug(gesture)
            label.text = gesture

            if (gesture == "shake") {
                window.state == "rotated" ? window.state = "default" : window.state = "rotated"
                timer.start()
            }
            if (gesture == "whip") {
                window.state == "whipped" ? window.state = "default" : window.state = "whipped"
                timer.start()
            }
            if (gesture == "twistRight") {
                window.state == "twistedR" ? window.state = "default" : window.state = "twistedR"
                timer.start()
            }
            if (gesture == "twistLeft") {
                window.state == "twistedL" ? window.state = "default" : window.state = "twistedL"
                timer.start()
            }
            if (gesture == "cover") {
                window.state == "covered" ? window.state = "default" : window.state = "covered"
                timer.start()
            }
            if (gesture == "hover") {
                window.state == "hovered" ? window.state = "default" : window.state = "hovered"
                timer.start()
            }
            if (gesture == "turnover") {
                window.state = "default"
                loopy2a_mono.play();
                timer.start()
            }
            if (gesture == "pickup") {
                window.state = "default"
                phone.play()
                timer.start()
            }
            if (gesture == "slam") {
                window.state == "slammed" ? window.state = "default" : window.state = "slammed"
                timer.start()
            }
            if (gesture == "doubletap") {
                window.state == "doubletapped" ? window.state = "default" : window.state = "doubletapped"
                timer.start()
            }
        }
```

and I can get whip, twist right, twist left, twist (not sso much but thats probably down to my own error),cover,pick up and slam. but the other ones not at all. some of them are not so important but these are the ones that I really need and having no luck. Double tap I'm getting nothing at all, and when I do hover left or right I get a delta x,y,z reading showing up in the console but with no luch as far as the gesture side of things. I also get an error which looks like this

```
D/SensorManager(26532): framework alsps raw_data dataX=0.0 dataY=7426.0 dataZ=9571.0
D/SensorManager(26532): open file /sys/bus/platform/drivers/als_ps/sys_prox_status error
D/SensorManager(26532): echo 0 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/als_ps/sys_prox_status
I/SurfaceTextureClient(26532): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x754f75b0) fps:47.44, dur:1011.90, max:41.40, min:10.39
```

and on my samsung galaxy note 2 all the above is the same except for on the hover function this is the out put I get

```
D/SensorManager( 3161): Proximity, val = 0.0  [close]
D/SensorManager( 3161): Proximity, val = 8.0  [far]
```

on double tap I get nothing.

Thanks again.

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have edited my post above in response to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should give an illustration of your problem to narrow it and/or some **compilation/debbuging outputs**.

1. I advice you to check your **project** file (Qt Creator) ***.pro** if it contains the sensors support, else **add** it as follow :

   QT +=  sensors
2. Try to compile your project in **different platforms** if you can and in the mean time check if the sensors library is **supported** by your **target platform**.

**### Update ###**

try this and see if you are getting readings from the Accelometer (the x,y reading are updated at **labelGesture**) :

```
 import QtQuick 2.0
 import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
 import QtSensors 5.0 as Sensors
 import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Rectangle {

id: gesturerect
width: Screen.width;
height: Screen.height

border.width: 1
anchors.margins: 5

property string selectedGesture: ""


Sensors.Accelerometer{

    id:accMeter
    active: true
    onReadingChanged: {
        var r= reading;
        labelGesture.text = "x : "+ r.x +" y : " +r.y 
    }
    Component.onCompleted: accMeter.start()
}
Text {
    id: labelGesture
    anchors.top: gesturerect.top
    anchors.left: gesturerect.left
    anchors.right: gesturerect.right
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    font.pixelSize: 30
    font.bold: true

}

Rectangle {
    id: gestureListRect
    border.width: 1
    anchors.top: labelGesture.bottom
    anchors.left: gesturerect.left
    anchors.right: gesturerect.right
    anchors.bottom: gesturerect.bottom
    anchors.margins: 5

    //! [4]
    ListView {
        id: gestureList
        //! [4]
        anchors.fill: gestureListRect
        anchors.margins: 5
        //! [5]
        model: Sensors.QmlSensors.sensorTypes()//gesture.availableGestures
        //! [5]
        focus: true
        currentIndex: -1
        delegate: gestureListDelegate
        clip: true
        //! [6]
    }
    //! [6]

    Component {
        id: gestureListDelegate

        Rectangle {
            width: gestureList.width
            height: itemText.height
            color: (index === gestureList.currentIndex ? "#999933" : "#FFFFFF")

            Text {
                id: itemText
                text: model.modelData
            }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    gestureList.currentIndex = index
                    selectedGesture = model.modelData
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Both worked for me , your example and the modified one by me.

**My environment** : win 7 64 , Qt 5.2.1 QtCreator 3.0.1 (MinGW 4.8 armabi-v7 Android )

**Target** : Android tablet (Archos 70b Titanium , OS 4.1 )

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have edited my post above in response to your question.

Comment: can you give more information ? like a small example (in qml code) with your PRO file .thanks

Comment: I have added the info you requested in my post. thanks

Comment: sorry for the late reply ,check the updated answer , Good luck

Comment: thank you again. Yeah i've tried this on my samsung galaxy note 2 and my vivo y20t (chinese brand but quite good and with a samsung like sensor at the front) and on the chinese brand i get this out put : D/VelocityTracker(22751): Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (No such file or directory)
D/VelocityTracker(22751): tpd read x fail: Bad file number
D/VelocityTracker(22751): tpd read y fail: Bad file number

Comment: and what im really trying to get out of this sensor class is he double tap function on the side and when you swipe across(4 cm above) the screen to do certain functionality